# How to remove only empty nodes in XML using Xpath expressions?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to remove empty nodes in XML using Xpath expressions .

Let's consider the below sample XML. In that, 'nickname' and 'height' nodes are not needed as they are empty.

**Original Data**

---

```
<class>
   <student rollno = "393">
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <nickname></nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
      <height></height>
   </student>
</class>
```

**Expected Data**

---

```
<class>
   <student rollno = "393">
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

Comment: XPath can only select nodes that are actually there, it can't change them in any way. To create a different XML tree, you need XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath with the predicate not(node()) to select all elements that do not have child nodes.

For example:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadxml('<parentnode>
   <tag1>2</tag1>
   <tag2>4</tag2>
   <tag3></tag3>
   <tag2>4</tag2>
   <tag3></tag3>
   <tag2>4</tag2>
   <tag3></tag3>
</parentnode>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->savexml();
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <parentnode>
     <tag1>2</tag1>
     <tag2>4</tag2>
     <tag2>4</tag2>
     <tag2>4</tag2>
   </parentnode>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression to target those empty elements is: `*[not(node())]`.

However, you can't transform the XML with XPath.

I would apply the following XSLT stylesheet, which has a default template that copies all content and one special template matching elements that do not have any child nodes (no element or `text()`) that is empty, which means those elements get dropped.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>            
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```